# Access Multiple Local Sites (same ip) By Host Name From Android

Tags: networking, dns, android, iis, hostname

I'm hosting several sites from my local machine for development purposes.  It's an odd mix of personal-use sites, dev sites for work, the dev site for my creative group's real site, and just the odd testing page for server-side code.  I have about five different sites active through IIS on my local machine.  I differentiate between them by url, what else!  I've modified my host file so I can access them.

But I can't modify the host file on my (android) phone unless I root it.  And I don't want to do that because then my mobile testing wouldn't be accurate.  I can make it work (kind of) if I type in the local ip address (in the 192.168.1.whatever range) in my phone browser, and then am able to access the site that I have bound to the blank hostname.

But I have at least 5 sites running.  I don't always remember which one I have bound to the blank hostname.  And I don't really like going into IIS every time to unbind that one and bind the one I'm currently working on.  Additionally, though I don't have it up yet, I might like to use a site to let friends and family access a picture server or whatever.  Or I might need to test different sites at the same time.  Or... or... or... Lots of use cases, beyond mere convenience.

Also, as far as I know, my residential AT&T Uverse router does not support DNS, so I can't change it on the router.  (And no, I cannot change the hardware at my grandma's house!  That's where I'm working out of.)

TLDR: How do I access a specific hostname at a specific local ip address through my android phone (and friend's android phones, and if it's easy to make the jump, maybe even iphones and tablets).  I am totally willing to type in a string of numbers and characters.

Comment: I think it is time for you to set up a dedicated server running your websites, dhcp and dns. That way you get control of everything. An alternative is to run DNS from your local machine rather than your router.

Comment: That's actually what I'm looking for.  How do I run DNS from my machine?  I didn't know I could do that, since most of the local devices don't ping each other on the way out to the web.

Comment: What OS is it running?   What do you mean the devices don't ping each other?

Comment: Windows 10 for my laptop/server, which is only on during development or gaming.  Android 6.0.1 for my phone.  I'm much more in programming than in IT, so I don't know all of the ins and outs.  But don't devices only ping each other when they have a specific purpose in talking to one another?  (Like a ping test, file transfer, gaming server, website etc.)  And perhaps I used "Sites" too loosely.  I only said "sites" because IIS Manager said it.

Comment: If you move DNS from your router to something else, then that something else would need to be on all the time in order for internet to work.  Do you have another machine - like a NAS box or something else that is always-on?

Comment: Um... I've got a RaspberryPi I could turn on and leave on.  I sadly don't use it for anything at the moment.  But this seems far more complicated than I originally thought.  I don't need friends and family to be able to type in something simple like "pictures.local"  I need to be able to type in `192.168.1.73:host=pictures.local` or something like that, and I can do that for each family member if need be.  But I really just need to be able to do that on my own phone.

Comment: You could just assign a port that is different from port 80 to each site and use that. So Site 1 would use port 80, site 2 16001 or whatever. That way you could use the IP to connect (`http://<ip>:16001` would be site 2). If you don't want that you will have to either root your android phone or setup a DNS server. It might also be possible to use sub-sub-domains with some kind of DynDNS setup but I'm not certain about that.

Comment: @RoboticRenaissance Seth's approach is a better solution. If you replace DNS on your network, it is for everything, not just your websites - for every day surfing.  This takes some learning.  Using different ports per site would simplify things.